# Increment date with Calendar class

Tags: java

I must add to a date 20 days. Day is incrementing but therefore month is not incrementing. How can I change day and month at the same time.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: You should look into Joda Time ( http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ ) it's a better library to handle dates.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class So15559346 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c=new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat();
        df.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,20);
        System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: if you execute this code a few times you will see that month is not changing.

Comment: it changes ok for me using eclipse and java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Calendar.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, number-of-days )`

Something like this should do:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( dateFormat.parse( inputDate) );
cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 20 );
```

But I would suggest you to use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library for handling date/calendar related stuff in Java.

Comment: I tried this code. For example today is 22 march. Add 20 to 22. ıt corresponds 11 april. but this codes shows 11.04.2013. when i added 20 days too, it shows 31.04.2013. Again add 20 days it shows 11.04.2013. this is the problem

Comment: instead of `Calendar.DATE`, try using `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. the reason is that i did not update from db

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //If you already have a date object then use the next line
    // currentTime = dateObj.getTime(); 
    long twentyDays = 20*24*60*60*1000;

    Date d = new Date(currentTime + twentyDays); //20+ days from today

    System.out.println(d.toString());
```

Comment: This might cause issues with edge cases if daylight savings applies.

Comment: The issue is actually daylight saving itself :/